# dockergento amasty elasticsearch can't find products

Tags: magento2, search, elasticsearch, amasty

I thought it was a problem of elasticsearch version, updated it still same error, tried reindexes and so on... on admin page everything seems to be fine anchor->yes and so on.
used that link [looked like a fix and solution](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/b027f7f5e4f6969455ac4766df926ffcbedae556) but after modifying my code and saving new 'elasticsearch' from admin I had nginx 502 error (on a specific page where the products must be).
any suggestion? I also used some queries,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW inventory_stock_1 AS select distinct legacy_stock_status.product_id AS product_id, legacy_stock_status.website_id AS website_id, legacy_stock_status.stock_id AS stock_id, legacy_stock_status.qty AS quantity, legacy_stock_status.stock_status AS is_salable, product.sku AS sku from ( cataloginventory_stock_status legacy_stock_status join catalog_product_entity product on (( legacy_stock_status.product_id = product.entity_id )));
```

multiple reindexes. still nothing

Answer (score 2):

-setted up hp project with clean database,added product for testing
- setted up elastic Search,
-on blank theme everything seems to be fine
-changed theme to hp and product was not visible anymore
-started debugging collection
-updated elasticSearch to 1.8.1
-saw product on home page(inserted catalog product list widget before) , then when I clicked  on it found error ->Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/devall/hp/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header-links.phtml on line 14.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5q5U.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMw4d.png
-installed hp on clean database once again to see if elasticSearch update was the thing.
-found out that category was not showing products anyway...
-had errors on product page even with mysql search, checked same on dev,there was not the same errors.
-maybe I'll use databaseDump again to check if it removes that product page errors and then debug Our themes collection